# Specific Partitioning Requirements

Tags: partitioning

I don't know how to do what I want to achieve. I want my computer to use LVM and have one volume group over the hard drive, which I will create a logical volume for root and for /home. I also want to install my bootloader on my USB (i.e. it won't be put on my hard drive). I don't even know where to start. I've got gparted open and I'm lost. I literally just don't know what to do. Please can you help me get this done.

So far I have just made 1 big partition, but now how do I make it use LVM and get a volume group and logical volumes on it?

Comment: for LVM I suggest following https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/advanced-installation.html#lvm .

Answer (score 0):

Manually set up lvm and your logical volumes, then choose the *something else* option when installing, and select your existing partitions, and the drive to install grub to.  You may want to read http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm.

Comment: I managed to get two volumes setup on a volume group. But what I couldn't figure out how to do was get GRUB onto the USB during the installation. How do you do that?

Comment: @johnsmith, there is a knob on the partitioning screen to choose where to install grub to.  Pick the USB stick.